# declare variables in sql 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my script i have few select statements and update statements, as an example

```
SELECT * from TABLE1
WHERE userID= 'US001'

UPDATE TABLE2
SET value= 'months'
WHERE userID='US001'
```

statements going so on, so in this i have to copy and paste userID to every statement.
i want to declare a variable and assign to userID to refer it, so i don't need to add userID number to every query and i need to execute

i have tried this

```
Delcare @theID userID
SET userID ='us001'
```

but didn't work it out

please let me know..
thanks

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to declare the type, and assign it. In Sql Server, variables are prefixed with `@`, like so:

```
DECLARE @theID NVARCHAR(20);
SET @theID ='us001';

UPDATE TABLE2 SET value= 'months' WHERE userID=@theID;
```

Comment: i did as mentioned for a select statement, but no date showing 
query run perfectly

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @theID varchar(10);
    SET @theID = 'us001';
```

In your statement you are declaring your variable as `userID`, which is not a valid data type.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the previous answers, in SQL Server 2008 and higher you can also declare and set the variable in a single line.

```
DECLARE @UserID NVARCHAR(20) = 'us001';
```

Comment: In Sql 2012, yes, but not in 2005 sadly.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, added it to the text.

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me under SQL2005 in a stored procedure:

```
    DECLARE @name varchar(100)
    SELECT @name = 'Robin'  

    // and this should be do the update
    SET userID = @name

   // or in you query it should be
   WHERE userID = @name
```